# string comparison by ignoring encoding

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding

I have two strings.

```
string one = "Montr�al";
string two = "Montréal";
```

what are the string comparisons needed or is string comparison even possible between these two strings to get them to equal each other. I have tired

```
if(one.equals(two)){
 //true
}
```

also tired

```
if(String.equals(one,two, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)){
//true
}
```

even tired the `String.Compare` method they all seem to fail. how do I get these two string equal each other.

Answer (score 0):

Convert them both to the same encoding first. If `string two` is utf then try

```
string one = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Montr�al"));
```

However, the `"Montr�al"` has to be read directly from the source, not written in the code editor.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string one = "Montr�al";
        string two = "Montréal";

        one = Translate(one);
        two = Translate(two);

        if (string.Equals(one, two, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Equal");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static string Translate(string input)
    {
        var output = new char[input.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var charCode = (int) input[i];
            if (charCode == 65533) // char �
                output[i] = (char)233; // é
            else
                output[i] = input[i];
        }
        return new string(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if a different letter was missing, other than `é`?